# Risks ot WPF classes in windows service

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, service

I'm hoping somebody will be able to provide some advice regarding a slightly unorthodox use of WPF.

We have a windows based C# server application which was originally written as a desktop application using WPF for the front end.

I've recently re-factored the application to split the functional components and the UI into distinct sections, so that there is currently a ServerCore class, and various UIs which implement the IServerFrontEnd interface.

The ServerCore dispatches log and status messages to the front end using the wpf Dispatcher, picked up through Application.Current.Dispatcher.

For WPF UI front ends, this is not a problem, but in the case of the console front end, it has necessitated extending the base Application class, and creating an application context when the application starts.

I realise that there have been many questions posted pertaining to the use of WPF in console or WinForms applications, but my concern is the possible pitfalls of using a WPF context to start a service.

I have tested and proven that a WPF application context can be created when the service launches, but have yet to do any large scale testing of the performance of the service under load.

As the server core only uses the WPF dispatcher for firing log and status messages to the UI (in this case, the windows service), I'm debating re-writing the core such that it will use internal logging for messages when run as a service, rather than using the dispatcher at all.

Does anybody have experience using the dispatcher within a windows service?

I am not averse to the notion of re-writing the core to only hook the dispatcher when running from a WPF gui application, but this would be an extensive re-write which I would like to avoid if it is not necessary.

Many thanks,
Alex

Comment: I would re-write the system to remove the dependency on WPF dispatcher. In all likelyhood it probably won't cause problems 99% of the time, but that 1% at 3am is really difficult to diagnose because its probably going to be some kind of vague, unhelpful exception that takes more time to trace down than to fix out of the gate. If you can refactor now, do it.

Comment: Hi Ron. Thanks, that was a really quick response! At the moment, that's what I'm leaning towards. The issue is that I need to retain the dispatcher for instances where we have a WPF front end that implements the server core, so I can not lose the WPF dependency entirely. I was hoping for a possible quick fix or a resounding cry of "no, it's fine", but the more I think about it, the more I'm leaning to a rewrite being the sensible option.

Comment: This is a good example of where to use a factory pattern. Create an `ILogger`, derive 2 loggers from it, the `HeadlessAppLogger` and `WPFAppLogger`. Then create a factory that you request loggers from returning an `ILogger`. You can determine which to use in the factory method so its transparent to downstream code. Its also easily upgraded or added to later if other needs arrive. I'd suggest though breaking out the non-ui-specific code into its own project and referencing it between the two.

Comment: I think that could be an ideal way to achieve this. It would be slightly less of a rewrite than the idea I had in mind, although it would require ultimately more new code to provide the various message routes we will need. It would be a great deal neater though.

Comment: Hi Ron - just to let you know, I've implemented a log factory to break the dependency on the WPF dispatcher for any application that doesn't have a UI. The factory checks whether there is a value for Application.Current, and if there isn't, it just returns a basic logger that dumps to the windows event log. If there is, it returns a logger that calls up the dispatcher for routing messages to the UI. There is a fairly noticeable performance improvement when running as a service now, and the memory footprint is a little smaller. Many thanks, you've been a big help!

Comment: @RonBeyer - Could you please add your comment regarding the factory pattern as an answer, and I will accept it.  I expanded on this further and have numerous implementations of the logger interface, all working very well. Many thanks.

Comment: @RonBeyer Ron, this is dredging up an old question from way back, but your comment proved to be exactly what I needed. Could you post it as an answer please and I can accept it as the correct answer?